# Getting Invalid syntax near keyword where

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server-2008

I am on the verge of finishing a web-project similar to `nike+` and `runkeeper`, it is a prototype for a company make running devices, anyhow I have stumbled upon a problem here, and I am getting a error message that says `Invalid syntax near keyword WHERE`. I cannot for the life of me figure it out.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (Session["Email"] == null) //If user is not logged in, send to startpage
    {
        Response.Redirect("~/UserPages/Default.aspx");
    }
    else if (!IsPostBack) 
    {
        //User info is selected from DB and put in textboxes
        SqlConnection con1 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["jaklin11ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [Users] WHERE Email = @Email", con1);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", Session["Email"].ToString());
        using (con1)
            {
                con1.Open();
                SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                if (rdr.Read())
                    {
                        imgProfileImageProfile.ImageUrl = rdr["ProfileImage"].ToString();
                        textProfileImageProfile.Text = rdr["ProfileImage"].ToString();
                        textFirstNameProfile.Text = rdr["FirstName"].ToString();
                        textLastNameProfile.Text = rdr["LastName"].ToString();
                        textHeightProfile.Text = rdr["Height"].ToString();
                        textWeightProfile.Text = rdr["Weight"].ToString();
                        textPasswordProfile.Text = rdr["Password"].ToString();
                        textBirthdateProfile.Text = rdr["Birthdate"].ToString();
                        textAreaCode.Text = rdr["AreaCode"].ToString();
                        textTown.Text = rdr["Town"].ToString();
                        ddlGenderProfileEdit.Text = rdr["Gender"].ToString();
                    }
            }

    }

}
```

Comment: Maybe try [Email]. Also disposing your SqlDataReader and SqlCommand.

Comment: @ta.speot.is `Email` is not a [_reserved keyword_](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx) on T-SQL. `;)`

Comment: Nope, still get Invalid syntax...

Comment: Yes I have, in the SQL Server 2008 I get this error message 

Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 16
Must declare the scalar variable "@Email"

Comment: Have you tried this query in SQL Server 2008 with an actual email address?

Comment: Googling suggests that the error message is "Invalid syntax near THE keyword WHERE" not "Invalid syntax near keyword WHERE". Maybe get the exact wording of the whole exception?

Comment: @andrejcurcic Please read a book about sql server.

Comment: @SonerGönül no need to be rude, I did in first year of my studies at the university Conolly and Begg Database systems. Still Iam finishing a project which was from the begining mostly coded by another devolper hence why some of the things are not commented and clear

Comment: @SonerGönül Your reference is quite the authority on reserved keywords so my suggestion is moot. I can't see what else could possibly be wrong syntactically, unless there's some hidden Unicode characters in the query or OP is showing us the wrong code.

Comment: @andrejcurcic You serious? As you say, you are new in this subject and I suggest you to read a good book about that before you start developing. I don't see anything wrong suggesting people to read books..

Comment: @ta.speot.is Of course, that's why OP should give more information about his problem. What are all values when he debug it? Is it working on Sql Server? etc.

Comment: Solved it! It was a minor issue in the database with one of the parameters that had been wrongly named. Thank you for all the answers and suggestions, wish you all the best.

Comment: @andrejcurcic Can you please add your answer to this post?